# PHP não recebe requisições POST

Tags: php, api, postman

Tenho o seguinte código no meu index.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

var_dump($_SERVER);
```

E faço uma requisição POST para ele.

Só não estou entendendo porque o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` está chegando como `GET` ao invés de `POST`.
Testei com outros métodos como `PUT` e `DELETE` e dá a mesma coisa.

[image: Requisição POST chega como GET]

Comment: Está usando algum framework? Seria o Laravel?

Comment: Estou perguntando isso, mas vou dar meu pitaco: Geralmente, requisições que tem redirecionamento, retornam `GET` aí no `REQUEST_METHOD`. Acho que pode está acontecendo com você

Comment: Não amigo, não estou usando nenhum framework. No caso, como eu resolveria isso? Tem um switch na API que olha o ['REQUEST_METHOD'], da forma como está não funciona direito....